# android - ListView and ArrayAdapter with simple_list_item_multiple_choice

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, multiple-choice

The following code creates an `ArrayAdapter` and I change the state of each `CheckedTextView` using `ListView.setItemChecked()` in `onResume()`.

This is all fine.

Is there a way I can disable (grey out) some of the `CheckedTextViews`?

I've tried using `adapter.getView(position, null, listView)`, and while this returns a `CheckedTextView` object, setting it to `setclickable(false)` doesn't do anything. I've tried changing its text and changing the state but it doesn't do anything either.

How can I achieve this?

Below is the code that works fine:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, 
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mode_declarations_array));

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);       

    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    String learningSettings = settings.getString(Constants.LEARNING_SETTINGS, null);

    int count = adapter.getCount();

    if (learningSettings != null ) {

        String[] values = learningSettings.split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i< values.length; i++) {

            boolean val = Boolean.parseBoolean(values[i]);

            listView.setItemChecked(i, val);

        }

    }else {
        for (int i = 0; i<count; ++i) {
            listView.setItemChecked(i, true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom adapter of yours and override  the `isEnabled` function.

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        // return false if position == position you want to disable
    }
}
```